# Cannot assign value from text input field to Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, scope, var

Each time I call the `malfun` function it keep displaying `0` instead of the product of the two numbers, and I'm not sure why. However, when I hard-code a value to `num1` and `num2` it works as expected.

```js
const num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
const num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;

function mulfun() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="firstNumber" placeholder="Enter the first value"><br>
  <input type="text" id="secondNumber" placeholder="Enter the Second Value"><br>
  <input type="button" id="multiply" value="Multiply" onClick="mulfun()">
</form>
<p>The Result is : <br>
  <span id="result"></span>
</p>
```

Can someone explain why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Because inittially you set the vars with the inputs content that is empty at the beggining. Then when you call the function you're not getting the values again, you're just using the values that were already in the vars (empty values).

Now if you move the consts inside the function each time the function is run you're re-getting the values and the math operation works fine.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're reading the value of input once, right after `document.getElementById` is executed instead of once the user clicks the button. You should dynamically access the value when the function is called. (When you declare those values, `num1` and `num2` would both be an empty string, and in JS `"" * "" === 0`.)

```js
const num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber");
const num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber");

function mulfun() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1.value * num2.value;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="firstNumber" placeholder="Enter the first value"><br>
  <input type="text" id="secondNumber" placeholder="Enter the Second Value"><br>
  <input type="button" id="multiply" value="Multiply" onClick="mulfun()">

</form>
<p>The Result is : <br>
  <span id="result"></span>
</p>
```